# bootstrap vue input form create file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I'm using bootstrap-vue with electron.

```
<b-form-file>
```

is for selecting existing files, but how would I use this component to simply select a file/directory path that doesn't exist yet so I can create and use it as a project repository (For the app I am working on)?